# How to prevent user view creation in MS Teams SharePoint List

Tags: microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online

I'm working strictly in Office 365 online. I have created an MS Team, which has automatically created an SP Team site. I created a new list on the SP Team site. I need members to only see things that have been assigned to them, which ultimately means I have to prevent them from being able to create or edit any views. In the SP site associated with the team, I changed the permissions for the edit permission level associated with the members group so that they can't create or edit views. Signed in as a member, and I can create and edit views. Any ideas? Is Teams overriding what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the original permission levels as they are. This can be done in the list.

There is an Advanced list setting to allow people to create new items and only read or edit the items that they have created. Go into the list settings, click Advanced, and turn on the desired setting.

This way, any view will show the user only the items that they have permissions to see.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I need users to only see items that are marked as assigned to them. There is an assigned to field un the list. So this won't work, and I'm becoming afraid the MS took away yet another very important capability.

Comment: You may need to create a new permission level instead of changing the Edit permissions. Then break the permission inheritance for that list and give the Members the new permission level.

Answer (score 0):

Please following steps:

1.Access the SharePoint list as a site administrator

2.**List settings** >> **Advanced settings**

[image]

3.On the Advanced Settings page, scrollto **Item-level Permissions** section, check "**Read items that were created by the user**" option and "**Create items and edit items that were created by the user**" option

[image]

[image]

========================= **Updated Answer** ========================

**Please following steps:**

1.List settings >> **Advanced settings** >> (Item-level Permissions) check "**Read items that were created by the user**" option

[image]

2.Go back List Settings page, scroll to **Views** section, click on the default view

3.On the Edit View page, scroll to Filter section. Check "**Show items only when the following is true:**" option and set **Assigned To is equal to [Me]**.

[image]

Comment: I need users to only see items that are marked as assigned to them. There is an assigned to field un the list. So this won't work, and I'm becoming afraid the MS took away yet another very important capability. –

Comment: I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Why are you repeating the approach that I already posted??

Answer (score 0):

I edited the edit permissions for the site. I deselected "manage personal views", but as mentioned, it still didn't work. I had to also deselect "manage lists" permissions. It also does a few more things than disable view creation by users with edit permissions but I'm ok with that. But, now I can no longer see view creation or editing capabilities if logged in as a member with edit permissions.

I could have created a new security group, but in this case, just changing the edit permissions is fine. The solutions above would not work because I want people to only see what has been assigned to them by an admin, so it has nothing to do with who created the item. The default view says to only show items where the "Assigned to" field is equal to [ME] and this is the only view they can see and cannot edit it or create a new one that would show things they are not supposed to see.